# plot boxplots from two datasets side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have two data frames and I want to plot boxplots for scores beside each other and each data frame boxplot has a different color.

| ID | score1 | score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 300 |
| 2 | 300 | 150 |
| 3 | 400 | -100 |

| ID | score1 | score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 200 | 300 |
| 300 | 300 | 150 |
| 400 | 400 | -100 |

Comment: Both data frames have ID, and score1 and score2 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

But fore reshaping the data, create a new column telling from which data set is this data and bind the two data sets.

```r
x <- '
ID  score1  score2
1   200     300
2   300     150
3   400     -100'

y <- '
ID  score1  score2
200     200     300
300     300     150
400     400     -100'

df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(textConnection(y), header = TRUE)

dfboth <- rbind(
  cbind(data = 1, df1),
  cbind(data = 2, df2)
)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

bind_rows(
  df1 %>% mutate(data = "1"),
  df2 %>% mutate(data = "2")
) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("score"), names_to = "score") %>%
  ggplot(aes(data, value, fill = score)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("Data set")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>